# XCode 4.2 - Has anyone else found Storyboard on Lion to be very buggy?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm using Storyboard in full screen on Lion with Xcode 4.2 . I'm encountering what appear to be several obvious bugs in the feature, and wondered whether anyone else is experiencing the same?

Here are a couple of the bugs I'm seeing:

1. GUI components can only be dragged onto view controllers after double clicking the controller. However, double clicking the controller zooms in beyond the point of controller fitting the screen, making positioning the new component nigh on impossible. Zooming out loses the controller focus and prevents adjustment of the new component.
2. Adding a new view controller to the Storyboard makes all controllers, including the new one, disappear from view. They can only be made to appear one-by-one by left clicking their View in the Storyboard components list on the left.

**UPDATE**

I actually solved this one before finishing writing the question (!) but thought I'd post for others.

It seems these bugs arise when you have the Storyboard open in two separate Xcode windows. I'd left clicked the storyboard once in my "main" Xcode window so it loaded there, then I double-clicked it to load in a new, separate window. With the original window open these bugs arise. However, as soon as one of the windows is closed, all issues disappear.

Comment: thanks for the update part. I also had two windows opened and it was disappearing. It's an obvious xcode bug. Really pissed me off.

Comment: Anytime, I too was shocked at how buggy it is...!

Comment: I was having the same issue with all of the components disappearing anytime I added a new view/controller.  Turns out I also had two storyboard windows open.  Not sure why this was closed...

Comment: The title of the question is probably the sole reason.   The title probably should have been something specific like "why does my storyboard disappear when I paste a view into it".  That's, roughly, what I just googled to come here.   Thank you for writing it up so that google could bring me here, and for updating with the answer.  You solved a frustrating head-scratcher for me!

Comment: For what it's worth, this also seems to happen if you have two tabs open with the same storyboard.